# children vs selector - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For the sake of simplicity I'll narrow down the question as below. I have a large code running in the click js functions. To represent that All I have added an `alert()`

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Test li 1</li>
  <li>Test li 2</li>
  <li>Test li 3</li>
  <li>Test li 4</li>
  <li>Test li 5</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

Method 1

```
$('ul li').click(function(){alert('hi');});
```

Method 2

```
$('ul').children().click(function(){alert('hi');});
```

Method 1 and method 2 both works fine.

Which one is better ? Is it better to use the selector or use the children method ? What's the purpose of having a children method when we can use selector?

***[Test Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yFX39/)***

I'm just grabbing the basics and hope not knowing something is not a crime. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both of those pieces of code work correctly on the sample HTML they are not identical.

`.children` returns all child elements (whether they are an "li" or not).

`"ul li"` as a selector returns all "li" descendants of the "ul" whether they are children or not.

These two are equivalent and select only "li" children of the "ul" parent:

```
$('ul > li').click(function(){alert('hi');});
$('ul').children("li").click(function(){alert('hi');});
```

As for which is better (the original question), there is no real answer for this I suspect and will depend on your actual requirements and html (when you ask for which is 'better' what do you mean? Performance? Maintainability?).

Usually the former will use the CSS selector engine of the browser where the selector you are using is supported, and the later will always use jquery built code (I think) so I would go for the former in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

as to

> Which one is better ?..

**updated**

actually, it depends on the HTML structure... if incase, you have small number of `<li>`'s in `ul` (first level)  going with children selector is better

you can check this in js.perf...[link here](http://jsperf.com/children-vs-selectors)

but if you have large number of `<li>` (in first level) the children selector gets slower ..

Comment: I modified your test, to just test what needs testing: [perf](http://jsperf.com/children-vs-selectors/2). The difference will kick in, if you have large nested structures, due to the fact that `children()` only traverses the first level.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the two are not actually equivalent, so the test isn't really a far one. Also, it will depend greatly on the structure of the actual HTML being used.

Comment: i agree.. :)... tried adding more `<li>` and yes, the `children` does get slower (even afselecting `<li>` of first level.......