# Which of these 2 methods is more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, dom, optimization

I always pay attention to efficiency when using JQuery since I know there is so much overhead. Which of the following two methods is more efficient, and why? Is there a way I can make it more efficient?

Method 1:

```
var percentString = percentDone.toString() + '%';
$('.progress-bar').css('width', percentDoneString);
$('.progress-bar > .sr-only').text(percentDoneString);
```

Method 2:

```
var percentString = percentDone.toString() + '%';
$('.progress-bar').css('width', percentDoneString).children('.sr-only').text(percentDoneString);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [children vs selector - jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933263/children-vs-selector-jquery)

Comment: https://jsperf.com/jquery-child-selector-vs-find/3

Comment: you hardcoded 1% in the second method

Answer (score 2):

My intuition is that Method 2 is more efficient. But how much more efficient depends on your DOM (total number of elements and how many elements have the `progress-bar` class). This is the kind of thing you should test. Here is an example of testing it:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-select-twice-versus-children

It show using Method 2 has a performance advantage over Method 1 as Method 2 allows ~18,000 operations a second while Method 2 is ~17,000 operations a second. My conclusion is it is so close that it doesn't matter. But that is with this very simple DOM:

```
<div class="progress-bar">
 <div class="sr-only">something</div>
</div>
```

It is important to consider if [micro-optimizations like this are important](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding) or if more [readable code is important](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/152392/is-it-ok-to-replace-optimized-code-with-readable-code) (I strongly favor more readable code -- in this case, I think Method 2 happens to be more readable/conventional).

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 uses the concept of jQuery chaining and thus it is much faster [**as explained here**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp)

The main reason is that accessing DOM elements by jQuery is always a bit slower, hence instead of accessing them each time it is better to apply all the methods at single selection(chaining)

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 would be more efficient, because Method 1 is repeating the selection of `'.progress-bar'`.

As is indicated in the link that `AnotherDev` posted in the comments, these two selections are equivalent functionally:

```
$('.progress-bar > .sr-only');

$('.progress-bar').children('.sr-only');
```

. . . and should be fairly similar as far as performance is concerned (this is dependant on the structure and content of your HTML, of course).

What is going to slow down Method 1 is that you are selecting both `$('.progress-bar')` **AND** `$('.progress-bar > .sr-only')`, whereas Method 2 reuses the existing `$('.progress-bar')` result as a base for finding the `'.sr-only'` children, rather than having to "refind" it.

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 would be more efficient but the difference would be so small you probably wouldn't notice any difference. I'd leave it to your own personal preferance